# textbox search like in google

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am using C#.net Windows form , and I need to create a search textbox which will display combo box values (similar to google search); The values displayed in the combo box will be values from the SQL 2005 database (example the user is searching on FirstName, the combobox will display all firstnames, which get filtered as the user types in more letters.... if user is searching on LastName, the combo box displays all LastName values in the database.. etc)

when I am doing the above task

I have written the sql query like this

```
SELECT  distinct(person_Firstname+''+person_Lastname) 
AS 
name FROM persondetails 
WHERE name Like '%'+@name+'%'
```

when I am executing this query it gives error like this --- must declare a scalar varaible

my aim is when i am entering first letter in textbox it will display all names starting with that letter like in google...

can any one correct this ....

```
private void tbautocomplete_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AutoCompleteStringCollection namecollection = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=88888;Initial Catalog=contrynames;Integrated Security=True");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT  distinct(person_Firstname+''+person_Lastname) AS name FROM persondetails WHERE name Like '%'+@name+'%'";
    con.Open();
    SqlDataReader rea = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (rea.HasRows == true)
    {
        while (rea.Read())
        namecollection.Add(rea["name"].ToString());            
    }
    rea.Close();

    tbautocomplete.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
    tbautocomplete.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
    tbautocomplete.AutoCompleteCustomSource = namecollection;
```

Comment: Edit your question to show the entire snipped of code where you insert the textbox's value into your SQL statement.

Comment: it gives error  like " must declare a scalar varaible"            at  cmd.excutereader() statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to build an AutoComplete feature in your app. You're only missing the parameter on your SqlCommand. Try this:

```
string searchFor = "%" + txtName.Text + "%"; //the string the user entered.

cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT  distinct(person_Firstname+''+person_Lastname) AS name
                    FROM persondetails 
                    WHERE person_Lastname Like @name
                    OR person_Firstname LIKE @name";

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", searchFor);
```

Your `WHERE` clause must use the column name in your table. It sounds as if you want to match either the first or last name columns with your search token.

```
 WHERE person_Lastname LIKE @name
    OR person_Firstname LIKE @name
```

Comment: Dear Campbell, thanks for ur help its working now ... but i have a small doubt.. I am doing another application, in that we just used a query not using any command parameters  and it is connected to mysql database with php ..so  is it possible not to add any parameter only using person firstname and person last name

Comment: @user: suggest creating another question for your MySQL+PHP question. I'm sure you'll get an excellent answer!

Comment: it gives error like this Invalid column name 'name'. In persondetails table i have three columns person_id and person_firstname and person_lastname would you pls give any suggestions

Comment: another doubt can we include  this one  ("%" + txtName.Text + "%" )in sql statement directly  with out adding  any parameter.

Comment: would pls suggest any idea about this can we include txtname.Text in sql query directly instead of taking parameter

Comment: @user: **use parameters**, period. You're vulnerable to SQL injection otherwise. No 'doubt' about it! Suggest creating a new question regarding PHP and MySQL if that's what you're asking about.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6331950/textbox-autocomplete-with-mysql dear campbell this is problem i have posted with php c# and mysql

Answer (score 0):

The functionality you're looking for is called AutoComplete. I'm not familiar with an AutoComplete control in Windows forms, but if there isn't a built in one, there will certainly be third-party controls that do this.

The AutoComplete control will likely provide an event callback where you can put your SQL query to provide the possible completions.

As for your SQL error, it looks like it might be an issue with column names, but it is difficult to tell without your schema.

**Edit:**

I see you're using an AutoComplete contol already. The problem in your SQL is that your `@name` parameter is in your query, but you haven't added the parameter to the `cmd` object, so it doesn't know what value to put there.

Comment: i have no idea,is there any possible to replace @name with person first name and person lastname.