# Textbox autocomplete with MySQL

Tags: c#, .net, sql, winforms, autocomplete

I am trying to do the text box autocomplete by using the code below, but it gives the error

```
ERROR :"Object reference not set to an instance of an object"
```

on this line:

```
for (int count = 0; count < dt.Rows.Count; count++)
```

Can anyone please help me?

```
private void tbMemberName_TextChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tbMemberName.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
    tbMemberName.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
    AutoCompleteStringCollection namec = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();

    //string search ="%"+ tbMemberName.Text +"%";
    //string @Name = tbMemberName.Text; 
    String sql =
        @"SELECT DISTINCT(member_Firstname +''+ member_Lastname) AS Name FROM members WHERE Name  Like '%'+tbMemberName.Text+'%'";
    DataTable dt = MemberFormHelper.GetData(sql, mf);
    if (dt.Rows.Count >= 0)
    {
        for (int count = 0; count < dt.Rows.Count; count++)
        {
            namec.Add(dt.Rows[count][Name].ToString());
        }
    }
    tbMemberName.AutoCompleteCustomSource = namec;
}
```

Comment: would any one pls help me out from this situation

Comment: please tag your question accordingly, use as much tags as you can, this will help get your questions answered.

Answer (score 0):

if the NRE is from this line

`for (int count = 0; count < dt.Rows.Count; count++)` then that can only mean `dt` is null.

so `MemberFormHelper.GetData(sql, mf);` is returning a null value. Either fix `GetData()` or check `dt` for null before the loop.

Comment: String sql = @"SELECT (member_Firstname +''+  member_Lastname) AS Name FROM members WHERE Name  Like '" + tbMemberName.Text + "'";  Its not working would you pls confirm aboce query is the correct one for mysql   pls...  It does not give any error

Comment: @user1 can you post the entire `MemberFormHelper.GetData()` method?

Comment: public static DataTable GetData(string sql, formMain mf)
    {
        string r = WebCalls.webClass.doPost(mf.gBaseUrl + "xxxx/xxxx/query.php", sql);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        System.IO.TextReader t = new System.IO.StringReader(r);
        try
        {
            ds.ReadXml(t);
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine(r);
        }
        if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
        {
            DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
            return dt;
        }
        else
        {         
        }
        return null;
    }

Comment: sorry it seems to be clumsy but i dont hav enough space for posting clearly but that is entire function for getdata

Comment: @user1 there is a path if `ds.Tables.Count` is not `> 0` then it returns null and I'm pretty sure that's what is resulting in `"Object reference not set to an instance of an object"`. If you don't think it should return null then I suggest you debug through that method and see why `dt.Tables.Count` is not `> 0'.

Comment: now i am not getting any error , but the textbox does not behave like  autocomplete textbox. would you pls confirm that sql query is correct one...

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT (member_Firstname +''+  member_Lastname) AS Name FROM members WHERE Name  Like 'ass'A first chance exception of type 'System.Xml.XmlException' occurred in System.Xml.dll                                                               i  got the error like this  would you pls help me out

Comment: can any one pls help me out from this situation

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
for (int count = 0; count < dt.Rows.Count-1; count++)
```

If the row count is 10, you need to loop from 0 to 9 (10-1).

Cheers